# php53_errors.log is 19 GB big!?! IIS

Tags: php, iis

I am running an IIS since one month now and just found out that the file php52_errors.log is already 19 GB big. How can I disable these logs?

Comment: disable log is not good. try to fix errors reported in error_log and analyze error_log how you can reduce it

Comment: The Problem is that all programms I tried are not able to open this 19 GB file!

Comment: Maybe you should take a first look into the configuration: look for file `php.ini`.

Comment: You cannot open a big file? Don't use a graphical clicki bunti, but a decent command line client like `less` or `joe`. Always reliable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to edit your php.ini file

run this php script

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

and look for the: `Loaded Configuration File` (it's near the top).

Open that file (you may need to stop your server software) and change

`log_errors`

and or

`log_errors_max_len`

There should be comments about the settings in the file but if not and you just want to disable the error logs you can set `log_errors` to `Off` (I wouldn't advise this)

Or if you just want to limit the number of log lines you can change

`log_errors_max_len` to something like `500` (I would advise this :)

Addition: I should also point out that you will need to restart your server for the changes to take effect.

Comment: BTW: I looked in the log and its always the same error: PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant w - assumed 'w' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\xxxxxx\xxxxx\xxxx.php on line 15

Comment: can you put line 15 into a comment here? I'll see if I can help

Comment: I'm going to take a guess that that line is frwite call, wrap the w with `'`'s

Comment: When I said fwrite above I meant fopen

Comment: So, it should be safe to make the php.ini change for the logs, dump the logs and restart the server?

Comment: Locally yes, I've done this a few times on various installations of wampserver on my local machine and it's fine, you can actually delete you log files altogether and it will be recreated.